# Dissolving polygons in a large dataset

Tags: python, postgis, ogr2ogr, dissolve, sqlite

I need to dissolve polygons by the ID attribute in a large dataset (+-1gb shapefile). I have been struggling to find an efficient method to do this. I have tried the following methods:

- Postgis ST_UnaryUnion
- SQLite ST_Union, ST_Collect (via OGR)
- MapInfo Dissolve

I have also tried splitting the data set into much smaller tiles (12mb -20mb in size) however the above mentioned processes still take more than 24 hours to complete these much smaller datasets.

Is there a more efficient method of performing a dissolve on such large datasets?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by dissolve by ID, perhaps show the query.

Comment: With regards to ID, it is a field attribute, it must dissolve all polygons with the same "ID".    The  sqlite statement is as follows  'SELECT ST_Collect(geometry),ID FROM  layer GROUP BY ID' @John Barça

Comment: you have an index on both ID and geometry? I am specifically referring to Postgis.

Comment: see if http://lin-ear-th-inking.blogspot.co.uk/2007/11/fast-polygon-merging-in-jts-using.html helps? It should be in geos by now

Comment: Infact see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63921/how-to-perform-a-cascaded-combine-from-python-script-in-qgis for an answer - I suspect this is a duplicate of that Q

Comment: @iant Thanks very much. I will give those options a try. It looks promising

Comment: Please **edit** the question to contain the number of features (storage size is irrelevant) in the input table, the expected number of features in the output table, what spatial and attribute indexing you have on the input, and an indication of the natural ordering of the table (physically ordered on the attribute on which to dissolve? Spatially ordered? Random order?) You should also experiment with alternate formats.

Comment: If you are able to deploy Hive (with Hadoop), you can try [ST_Aggr_Union for Hive](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/08/16/st_geometry-aggregate-functions-for-hive-in-spatial-framework-for-hadoop/).

Comment: What's the cardinality of the ID? That would play a role in performance.  Either way that is suspiciously slow - what type of hardware?

Comment: @hdizzle The cardinality on the ID is very low, essentially the ID just represents different landcover types. I don't think the hardware is so much an issue as I have tried to run this on different spec machines, the weakest of the lot being an AMD Phenom(tm) II X6 1090T processor with 16GB of RAM.

Comment: What is the data? Is it a raster that has been converted to cells? If so there are probably better ways of creating the dissolved polygons directly from a grid. How are is the group id distributed? How many group values are there? A shapefile that is 1 GB is too large, it should be in a geodatabase.