# performance problem with PyQGIS: manipulating attributes

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, performance

I have selected a vector layer with attributes slope and area. I want to combine all the features with slope 0 to 5, 5 to 10, ... , 85 to 90. The original features are to be discarded, and new features for each slope-category are to be created (consisting of combined geometry, and combined area attribute).

I am pretty new to python programming, and while the script I created below seems to do what I expect (?), it has performance issues. It begins reasonable fast, but then slows down to a painfully slow speed.

I wonder what the reasen is for this behaviour, and what I could do better (and why) ?

```
import math
layer = iface.activeLayer()
for slope_cat_nr in range(1, 19):
    print "Slope Category: ", slope_cat_nr*5
    slope_max = 5*slope_cat_nr
    slope_min = slope_max - 5
    if slope_min == 0:
        slope_min = -0.001
    newGeom = QgsGeometry.fromWkt('GEOMETRYCOLLECTION()')
    anzF = layer.featureCount()
    onePercentAnz = math.ceil(anzF / 100)
    print "Nr. of Features: ", anzF
    progress = 0
    fIds = []
    for f in layer.getFeatures():
        if (progress % onePercentAnz) == 0:
            print (100*progress / anzF),
        progress += 1
        if f['slope'] > slope_min and f['slope'] <= slope_max:
            newGeom = newGeom.combine(f.geometry())
            fIds.append(f.id())
    newFeature = QgsFeature(layer.pendingFields())
    newFeature.setAttribute('slope', slope_max)
    newFeature.setAttribute('area', newGeom.area())
    print "New Area: ", newGeom.area()
    newFeature.setGeometry(newGeom);
    layer.dataProvider().addFeatures([newFeature])
    layer.dataProvider().deleteFeatures(fIds)
```

Comment: Your code seems ok. PyQGIS can be slow when manipulating geometries. You could give a try to [Shapely and Fiona](http://www.macwright.org/2012/10/31/gis-with-python-shapely-fiona.html).

Answer (score 2):

The code looks fine, but I'd expect the performance to get worse over time.

Each time round the inner loop, you're combining the current feature's geometry with the union of all the previous matching features' geometries.

At the start you'll have one simple geometry. Each time round the loop, the geometry gets more complex, so each time round the loop it will take a bit longer.

The time it takes to run `combine()` will depend on the complexity of the geometry, which is why the loop will slow down over time.

+1 to ArMoraer's suggestion of using Shapely/Fiona. I'd suggest you look at [cascaded union](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#shapely.ops.cascaded_union) and see if that's faster.. not tried it myself, but [there's a code example in this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/63935/55203) which you can try

Answer (score 2):

You initiate newGeom as GEOMETRYCOLLECTION, but in the loop you combine geometries. `combine` is the geometric union operation and as such has a much greater job than simply adding a geometry to a collection. It must check topological relationship on a low level, and if objects are disjoint it aggregates them to MultiPolygon geometries.

When I interpret your code right then what you want to do is to aggregate geometries to collections. This is what `addPartGeometry()` does. It aggregates objects to GeometryCollection of Polygon.

Since I haven't a useful dataset at hand to check performance I suggest you replace

```
newGeom = newGeom.combine(f.geometry())
```

with

```
newGeom.addPartGeometry(f.geometry())
```

and compare the running time.